# IJulia.notebook() command doesn't execute and block terminal

Tags: ijulia-notebook

I recently updated the new version of Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5. I am not sure this is the problem, I just mention it because last time I used IJulia was before updating my version of MacOS.

Now when I try to open IJulia notebook it blocks the terminal. Nothing happens at all, while before the notebook would open automatically. 
`using IJulia;` works fine, but `IJulia.notebook()` doesn't work. I updated everything and even reinstalled everything, same phenomenon.

Has everyone already had this type of issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocking is the normal behavior for the `notebook()` command. So the problem seems to be that it is not automatically launching the browser with the correct URL. There could be any number of reasons for that, and they could be related to your OS upgrade. Try opening the URL while the `notebook()` command is blocking.

Something like `http://localhost:8888/tree` is what I would expect for the URL.